# How to Sort Map Objects using object values

Tags: javascript

How do I sort this kind of map using the field lastSeen

```
var clients = new Map();
clients.set("BOJ_iPWtI7jVvG_pAAAH", {name: "John", lastSeen: 1608192766697});
clients.set("cShpndAsircj4_P4AAAN", {name: "Doe", lastSeen: 1608192862339});
```

How do I sort this clients map using lastSeen.

I have tried like this:

```
var sortedClients = new Map([...clients.entries()].sort((a,b)=>b.lastSeen - a.lastSeen));
```

but it is not working so I know I am not doing the right thing.

Comment: log `a` and `b` values inside the compareFunction. `entries` returns an array of key-value pairs. So, `a` will be something like: `["BOJ_iPWtI7jVvG_pAAAH", {name: "John", lastSeen: 1608192766697}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `b[1].lastSeen` instead of `b.lastSeen` and the same for `a` as well, because the attribute `lastSeen` is actually in index 1 for each entry in `clients`.

```
var sortedClients = new Map([...clients.entries()].sort((a,b)=>b[1].lastSeen - a[1].lastSeen));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following,

```
var clients = new Map();
clients.set("BOJ_iPWtI7jVvG_pAAAH", {name: "John", lastSeen: 1608192766697});
clients.set("cShpndAsircj4_P4AAAN", {name: "Doe", lastSeen: 1608192862339});
var mapAsc = new Map([...clients.entries()].sort((a, b) => {
  if(a[1].lastSeen > b[1].lastSeen) {
    return -1;
  } else if(a[1].lastSeen < b[1].lastSeen) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}));
console.log(mapAsc);
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I understand what goes on inside the sort(); but I'll accept @PIG208 answer cause it's precise.